# Getting the value of each Spinner from multiple Listview rows?

Tags: android, android-intent, serialization, android-listview

I have a custom List View. This is displaying a product image a spinner (product size dropdown) and a price on each row.

The user will pick a size for the products then press a button for sumbiting the selected products together with the proper sizes.

In the activity which opens next I would like to show the order with the total number, price and size of the selectes products.

How could I loop trough and get the value for each row of the listview so I can calculate and show the total price and selected spinner entries (there is no database, values are added by the user)?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

you can get the values for different spinners like this

```
String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

similarly for others values like total number,pice and size etc. and then you can pass these values via intent to other activity and get these values in the activity via getIntent()

Comment: Thanks, but there would be multiple values on each row, so I guess I will have to use an object to hold all of that. But you see I need to get values from let say 50+ rows, so I need too loop trought them from the activity that hosts the list view than pack up the results in an object which I can send via seralizable.

Comment: i think its a good approach just check for null if any item is not selected in a spinner